# Making a timer using setInterval function in javascript but haveing problem with it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, setinterval

I am making a timer using `setInterval` function  in Javascript.

I make one set button and one delete button which will set/delete the interval when pressed it.

Here is my code:

```js
    var interval;
    function sets(){
      interval = setInterval(function(){
       document.querySelector('div').textContent = 
        parseFloat(document.querySelector('div').textContent)+1; 
      },1000);
     };
    function del(){
      window.clearInterval(interval);
      document.querySelector('div').textContent = 0;
    };
```

```html
    <button onclick = 'sets()'>Set</button>
    <button onclick = 'del()'>Delete</button>
    <div>0</div>
```

I found that when I keep pressing the set button, the `div.textContent` will increasing faster and faster as I pressed more the set button.

Do anyone know why does this happens and is there some ways that i could avoid it without making two buttons into one button?

Thanks for any helps and responds.

Comment: Because you are creating new intervals each time before clearing any previous ones, just do `clearInterval(interval)` before creating the new one

Comment: Pressing the set Button is starting a new interval.
Clear any existing intervals before starting in sets() function

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+setInterval+becomes+faster) of [setInterval going too fast](/q/21099848/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the previous interval if `interval` is assigned already

```js
var interval;

function sets() {

  // Here you can check if the interval is assigned already
  // If assigned, use del() to clear it
  if (interval) {
    del()
  }

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('div').textContent =
      parseFloat(document.querySelector('div').textContent) + 1;
  }, 1000);
};

function del() {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
  document.querySelector('div').textContent = 0;
  interval = null;
};
```

```html
<button onclick='sets()'>Set</button>
<button onclick='del()'>Delete</button>
<div>0</div>
```

Comment: The `if(interval)` check will never be false again once this has been started. You’re never resetting the `interval` variable. Clearing the interval doesn’t automatically reset the `interval` variable.

Comment: My mistake for using the wrong term. Updating the answer

Comment: @Yilmaz i just wonder how do you make the interval become false?

Comment: @Shawn What do you mean by _“make the interval become false”_? You can set `interval = null;` or so, but it depends on what you expect your button to do when clicked multiple times.

Comment: In this case you can leave it as it is since you only want to clear the interval if exists. But you can use `interval = null` to remove the reference to the interval object. As @SebastianSimon stated, if you want to ignore the concurrent clicks to the `Set`, you can wrap the `setInterval` with an `else` block

Comment: @HarunYilmaz There was no wrong term. The `if` was just mostly useless in the original post. Note that _resetting_ on clicking the `Set` button is only one of many options. Another would be to just ignore the click. Shawn should specify what is supposed to happen. Also, there is no “reference to the inveral object”; there isn’t even an interval object. `setInterval` returns an integer which identifies the timer, nothing more.

Comment: OK, so `null` make the interval become nothing, doesn't it?

Comment: @Shawn No, `interval = null` makes `if(interval)` not pass.

Comment: @ Sebastian Simon, sorry, I feel confused by your comment, you said `interval = null `makes `if(interval)` not pass, then how do the `del()`  be called in the `set()` function.

Comment: @Shawn If you click `Del`, you make the `interval` `null`. So you don't need to call `del()` in the `sets()` function. But if you click `Set` before clicking `Del`, you need to call `del()` to clear the interval first in order to avoid multiple intervals modify the `textContent` of the `div` (if you want this behavior though)

Comment: @Shawn `if(interval){ del(); }` works just fine. In this case, there is no difference; my first comment was just a nitpick rather than pointing out an error. If `interval` contains a timer ID, `if(interval)` will pass (i.e. execute the body of the `if` statement) and `del` will be called and reset the timer. Otherwise, it won’t be called. `if(interval)` will only not execute its body at the very start, when no interval was running before (when `interval === undefined`), or after calling `del` (after which `interval === null`).

Comment: Guys, thanks for helping. My problem is solved:)